# Spring Web MVC 404 error – deployed as root on a webhost Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404, root

This is driving me crazy. Please help.

I am new to Spring and I developed my first spring mvc web app using sts/eclipse. It runs perfect inside eclipse’s tomcat server.

The application context is `/realtyguide` and I run it in eclipse at `http://localhost:8080/realtyguide/`

Here is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">

  <display-name>Realty Guide</display-name>

      <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>

      <!-- Handles Spring requests -->
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my root-context.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

</beans>
```

Here is my Spring application servlet configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springproject.realtyguide" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->    
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>   

    <!-- Allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" by forwarding static resource requests to the container's default Servlet -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>      


    <!-- Bean to provide Internationalization  -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/i18n/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="classpath:META-INF/spring/database.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- __________ BEAN ENTRIES FOR TILES 2 -->

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" >
        <property name="order" value="0"/> 
        <property name="viewClass"> 
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView </value>
        </property>
        <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="requestContext"/>
        <property name="viewNames" value="*.tiledef"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jstlViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="order" value="1"/> 
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
        </property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/> 
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/> 
    </bean> 

    <!-- __________ END OF BEAN ENTRIES FOR TILES 2 -->

    <!-- Resolves localized <theme_name>.properties files in the classpath to allow for theme support -->
    <bean id="themeSource" class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
        <property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme-" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="themeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">  
        <property name="defaultThemeName" value="standard" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is my controler's handler method for the root

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupForm(
        @ModelAttribute("searchFormBean") SearchFormBean searchFormBean, 
        Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("searchFormBean", searchFormBean);
    // 'index' is a Tile definition in tiles.xml
    return "index.tiledef";
}
```

This is my webhosts tomcat/conf/**server.xml**

I deleted most of the 'commented out' stuff to make it shorter.

```xml
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

                <Server port="9200" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

                  <!-- Comment these entries out to disable JMX MBeans support used for the 
                       administration web application -->
                  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" />
                  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
                  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
                  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreConfigLifecycleListener"/>

                  <!-- Global JNDI resources -->
                  <GlobalNamingResources>

                    <!-- Test entry for demonstration purposes -->
                    <Environment name="simpleValue" type="java.lang.Integer" value="30"/>

                    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
                         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users -->
                    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
                              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
                       description="User database that can be updated and saved"
                           factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
                          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" readonly="true" />

                  </GlobalNamingResources>


                  <!-- Define the Tomcat Stand-Alone Service -->
                  <Service name="Catalina">


                    <!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
                    <Connector port="9201" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                               maxThreads="10" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75"
                               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
                               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />

                    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
                    <Connector port="9203" 
                               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" />


                    <!-- Define the top level container in our container hierarchy -->
                    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">


                      <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
                           resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
                           that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
                           available for use by the Realm.  -->
                      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>


                      <!-- Define the default virtual host
                           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
                       -->
                      <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
                       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
                       xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

                       </Host>

                    </Engine>

                  </Service>

                </Server>
```

### My Goal

Bring up the index page of the site at `example.com`, without the extra `/.../` after the domain name.

### What I Did

Deployed as Root of Virtual Host on a Shared  Webhost:

I read on stackoverflow that I need to deploy as root so...

I packaged it in STS/Eclipse by: right click on project “realtyguide” > Run as > Maven package

Webhost server is  a private Tomcat 5.5. I deployed the war file (unzipped it) on my webhost as default application of virtual host (with Context `path = ""` in server.xml) so I can access the website as `example.com` and not `example.com/realtyguide`.

Success. Or so I thought. I am able to bring up the index page at `http://example.com/`

### Problem

Access to the other web pages referenced from the index page return a 404 error:

> The requested URL /realtyguide/page-name was not found on this server

Even though the browser address bar show the context path with a complete URL of *http://www.example.com/**realtyguide**/page-name*

I think the app is bypassing the spring dispatcher servlet, hence  not recognizing the context path, ‘realtyguide’, in the request URL  - resulting in a 404 error.

I am so lost on how to deal with this.

Questions:

1. What can I do to bring up the index page of the website at `example.com` instead of `example.com/realtyguide/` without breaking the app? I’ve tried a index.jsp file (in WEB-INF) forwarding to the index of the context path but it doesn’t solve the problem. Maybe I was doing it wrong.
2. Is there some forwarding mechanism that I can use so that a site visitor enters `example.com` and is immediately forwarded to the index page at `example.com/realtyguide/` so that all URLs shall be handled by the app?

Am I thinking about the problem the right way? Any solutions you’ve used before?

I’d greatly appreciate your help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is there a reason that you post no code whatsoever?  It can be impossible to help you if you do not provide us some *helpful* insight into what is going wrong...

Comment: My bad. Please see edited post with my configuration files and controller handler method.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Edited my post to include my webhost's tomcat/conf/server.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your web application the default web application for Tomcat.  Instructions are here:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F

Once that's done, it's easiest to use the index.jsp to forward to your Spring application's index.

An index.jsp file in the WAR root containing the following should do it:

```
<jsp:forward page="/realtyguide/" />
```

Comment: As per the instructions on the link you provided, I will deploy directory-and-files structure under the /webapps/ROOT directory. What do you mean by WAR root for the index.jsp file? Do you mean directory at '/webapps/ROOT' or '/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF'? I just want to be sure I'm doing it right. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I edited my post to include my webhost's conf/server.xml and I also followed the instructions on the link except the last part that requires editing the web.xml to include a servlet mapping for 'My First Servlet'. I assumed that the forwarding index.jsp file will replace this. But I got a 404 error of "The requested resource (/realtyguide/) is not available." Is that servlet mapping really necessary with the index.jsp file?

Comment: The index.jsp file should be in the subdirectory of your WAR file.  If you WAR file is exploded (or if you unzip it), it should be directly inside the "realtyguide" directory (assuming your WAR file is called realtyguide.war).  In your case, it will be under "webapps/ROOT" directly.

Comment: I followed your instruction  and deployed at /tomcat/webapps/ROOT directory. I also used an index.jsp  containing <jsp:forward page="/realtyguide/" /> under the ROOT directory.  But problem still persist. The index page comes up but access to the other web pages referenced from the index page still return a 404 error:  _“URL /realtyguide/ was not found on this server.”_  What else can I do to to access spring's application context 'realtyguide' when the app is deployed as root? Do you have other suggestions that I can try? Thanks.

Comment: Since you moved your WAR contents to the ROOT directory, it is no longer available at /realtyguide/.  It's available at "/".  If you want the site to be available at /realtyguide/, you need to do the following: (1) move the WAR back to the webapps/realtyguide directory, (2) restore the ROOT directory to the default Tomcat webapp, and (3) modify the webapps/ROOT/index.jsp file so it forwards to your application's directory (i.e. /realtyguide/index.jsp or whatever your landing page is).